# How to write promise function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that query the database, as i know that query that the function that queries the data is asynchronous functions. The problem is how can I write promise for the code below to be synchronous where in I need to put parameters inside the query function. I partially know how promise function works but as a beginner its hard to write something like that.

```
getTotalValues(){
 for(let weekrecords of this.week_records){
  this.selectPresentWeekData(weekrecords.weekid,weekrecords.croppingid); // asynchronous functions contains query in database
  this.loopThroughValues(); // must get the value from the query 
  this.loopObjectAccess(); // calculates the total using the values from the query
  this.pushDataToShow(weekrecords.weekid); // push the query data to a new object
}}
```

the operation of this function is like this

- Query to database -> store to object -> object to be extracted -> then calculates -> the calculated values will be stored to a new object array

Any suggestions will do thanks

Comment: `The problem is how can I write promise for the code below to be synchronous`. That'd still be asynchronous with the promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@behrooz is right, you need to ensure you are returning a promise that resolves when all the async work is done. In your method `selectPresentWeekData` you have 3 queries. Each query returns a promise and you process the data. So you need to wait for all 3 to finish and then resolve. You can assign each of those queries to a variable. That way you are storing the promises.

```
const x = db.query(...).then(...).catch(...);
const y = db.query(...).then(...).catch(...);
const z = db.query(...).then(...).catch(...);
```

In this situation each one of those will execute concurrently and finish whenever. Using `Promise.all()` we can know when all 3 have finished.

```
return Promise.all([x, y, z]);
```

By returning the `Promise.all` you are effectively saying that you want to wait until all 3 operations are finished. Then you can use the code that @behrooz offered or if performance matters and you'd like each iteration to run concurrently:

```
async function getTotalValues() {
  const presentWeekData = this.week_records.map(({ weekid, croppingid }) =>
    // for each record call your async, promise returning function
    this.selectPresentWeekData(weekid, croppingid)
      // when it finishes do these things
      .then(() => this.loopThroughValues())
      .then(() => this.loopObjectAccess())
      .then(() => this.pushDataToShow(weekid))
  );
  // now return a promise that waits for all those operations to finish
  return Promise.all(presentWeekData);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is the answer and also behrooz answer, it get what i want but still i get some errors. I might explore for more, thanks btw cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await to solve this problem. You can make the outer function as an `async` function and then use the `await` keyword for any asynchronous calls inside that function.

```
async getTotalValues(){
 for(let weekrecords of this.week_records){
   await this.selectPresentWeekData(weekrecords.weekid,weekrecords.croppingid); // asynchronous functions contains query in database
   this.loopThroughValues(); // must get the value from the query
   this.loopObjectAccess(); // calculates the total using the values from the query
   this.pushDataToShow(weekrecords.weekid); // push the query data to a new object
 }
}
```

Also, you have to make sure your `selectPresentWeekData` method is returning a promise, so `await` waits for that promise to resolve.

You can read more about async/await in JS (and TS) here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: still it jumps to loopthroughvalue function which is not right, i dont know whats the problem with this. maybe because selectpresentweekdata is quering multiple table this is the file from my github https://github.com/kevinpallado/cost-return-bis/blob/master/src/pages/weekrecords/weekrecords.ts

Comment: It seems that your `selectPresentWeekData` method is not returning any promises.

Comment: thats the thing im trying to figure out that the function that queries database must stop on some part. I really dont have idea how to write promises since this is my first use of javascript

Comment: First, your function (`selectPresentWeekData`) should return the promise it creates (`this.sqlite.create`). Second, inside the `then` for that promise, you cannot have several promises created randomly, instead, they have to be chained, so once one is finished, then the other one is executed. Since your reusing the database object, once each inner promise is resolved, you should return the db object so that the next promise can reuse it.

Comment: can you check my repo again i updated the code, i dont really sure if the syntax is correct or i am dumb enough not to understand your answer